# How to use single Django Template for multiple purpose

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have different **django models** which are identical e.g

- ItemCategory
- InventoryCategory
- MenuCategory
- ExpenseCategory

All of these models carry same attributes.

I want to use single *html page* which is **category_list.html** for displaying these models as list. I don't want to use different pages like **item_category_list.html**, **inventroy_category_list.html**, **menu_category_list.html** and so on. Every page contains **page header** which is actual kind of title of page represented in **h1** tag. I want to change with respect to currently loaded page.

**Note:** I am using **Generic Views** for Listing Items and I am currently using context for recognizing which view is sending response.

Any help would be appreciated.

**views.py**

```
class ItemCategoryList(ListView):
    model = ItemCategory
    template_name = 'app/category_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['page'] = 'Item'
        return context


class InventoryCategoryList(ListView):
    model = InventoryCategory
    template_name = 'app/category_list.html'


class ExpenseCategoryList(ListView):
    model = ExpenseCategory
    template_name = 'app/category_list.html'
```

**models.py**

```
class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/item_categories/", null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class InventoryCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/inventory_categories/", null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ExpenseCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/expense_categories/", null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: If all the models have the same attributes, does it make much sense to define these as separate models in the first place? You can restrict the queryset to which a `ForeignKey` can point. So you can define a `type` attribute to a hypothetical `Category` model.

Comment: Would you post the code of your view so far?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, Can you please provide any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not class based but my solution for this simply would be :

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/categories/", null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/$', views.ItemCategoryList, name='category')
```

home.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'category' 'ItemCategory' %}">Item Category</a>
<a href="{% url 'category' 'InventoryCategory' %}">Inventory Category</a>
```

category_list.html:

```
{% block title %}{{category.name}}{% endblock %}

{% for l in list %}
    {{l}}
{% endfor%}
```

views.py:

```
def ItemCategoryList(request, category):
    list = Category.objects.filter(name=category)
    category = category
    context{
      'list':list,
      'category':category
           }
    return render(request, 'app/category_list.html',context)
```

Comment: I am using this kind of approach, but I also have to use `get_absolute_url` method with each **category model**, how I can be able to use them?

Comment: Maybe something like this, so you can pass category name to your url in this way : `def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse("category", kwargs={"category": self.name} )`